# How to import a Python package into Google Colab?

Tags: python, package, google-colaboratory

I would like to not only import several python modules/files into Google Colab, but an entire directory (which might itself have sub-directories).

Comment: What did you try, and what error did you encounter? Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe?

Comment: @BobSmith Using the Upload feature on the File tab, it seems to me I can only upload files, not directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest mechanism to synchronize a directory is to use the [Drive FUSE client](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA)

To mount your Drive files on the Colab backend, run:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Then, you can upload files to `drive.google.com`, or use [Backup and Sync](https://www.google.com/drive/download/backup-and-sync/) on your desktop to sync directories efficiently.

Comment: Thanks Bob. How would I import specific modules from Drive after mounting it? The first link you provide only talks about reading from and writing to files from Drive.